# How do I play system sound in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, system-sounds

I want to play a "beep" sound from flutter.
I did try to use SystemSound.play but it doesn't seem to work.
Please help!.thank in advance.

```dart
Future<void> play(SystemSoundType type) async {
    await SystemChannels.platform.invokeMethod<void>(
      "SystemSound.play",
      type.toString(),
    );
}
void main() {
    play(SystemSoundType.click);
}
```

Comment: @pskink I don't know I just follow the implementation on the doc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**> 1.use this**

soundpool: ^0.5.3 lib in pubspec.yaml

**> 2.import this**

import 'package:soundpool/soundpool.dart';

**> 3.example**

```
Soundpool pool = Soundpool(streamType: StreamType.notification);

int soundId = await rootBundle.load("sounds/dices.m4a").then((ByteData soundData) {
              return pool.load(soundData);
            }); int streamId = await pool.play(soundId);
```

Comment: thanks, I also want to have a vibration does the lib also provide me that